# ¿Es posible añadir un sello de tiempo (tipo Xades-T) a un archivo xml sin firma digital?

Tags: c#, xml

Estoy casi segura de que no se puede, porque el [estándar Xades](http://www.w3.org/TR/XAdES/#XML_Advanced_Electronic_Signature_Data_Structures_Contents_of_XAdES_T) dice que el sello de tiempo [es añadido a la firma](http://www.w3.org/TR/XAdES/#XML_Advanced_Electronic_Signature_Data_Structures) como una extensión de la firma Xades. Además, [librerías como ésta](https://www.microsoft.com/france/openness/ressources/telechargement.aspx) requieren una firma Xades válida antes de añadir el sello de tiempo )lo que hace esta librería es "inyectar" el sello de tiempo a una firma digital ya existente).

Quieor estar 100% segura de que no es posible, porque me está confundiento el hecho de que cualquier archivo puede tener un sello de tiempo (usando el hash del archivo), pero el sello de tiempo correspondiente está en un archivo separado, usualmente con la extensión ".tsr" (¿timestamp response?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo entiendo que para que sea XADES-T es necesario realizar una firma válida (que tendrá su política de firma) para que la autoridad certificadora aproveche y te añada el timestamp de una Autoridad de Tiempo:

**XAdES-BES**   Forma básica que simplemente cumple los requisitos legales de la Directiva para firma electrónica avanzada

**XAdES-EPES**  Es un XAdES-BES al que se le incorpora información sobre la política de firma, como pudiera ser aquella información sobre el certificado empleado y la CA que lo emitió.

**XAdES-T** (timestamp)     Es un XAdES-EPES al que se le añade una segunda firma, pero en esta ocasión, una firma realizada por una TSA (Time Stamp Authority). Esta segunda firma aporta información específica sobre la fecha y hora exacta de la firma.

ref: https://www.viafirma.com/es/xades-firma-electronica-avanzada-xml

Otra cosa es que no necesites que un tercero te garantice la autenticidad y la integridad y te fíes (tu y tus usuarios) de cómo lo hace vuestro sistema. Entonces puedes meter la firma con timestamp como "attached" o en otro fichero como "dettached".

ref: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html